# Autoit click keys at the same time

Tags: timer, key, autoit

How do I click keys at the same time in AutoIt?

The keys I need are the following: <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

I tried this

```
Send("{RCTRL}")
Send("{RALT}")
Send("{RSHIFT}")
Send("{+}")
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
Send("!+n")
```

Notice that it sends a lowercase n. In most instances that is what you want to do or you could get unexpected results.

Here is the same code with an uppercase n.

```
Send("!+N")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Send("{CTRLDOWN}")
Send("{ALTDOWN}")
Send("{SHIFTDOWN}")
Send("{+}")
Send("{CTRLUP}")
Send("{ALTUP}")
Send("{SHIFTUP}")
```

Comment: hmm that did not work

Comment: hey ale, there must be something wrong with your autoIt. Me and @Amadan sent your the same awnser and in linked post of cvakiitho it says the same. I suggest you reinstall autoIt or give us more information. By the way, for what do you need CTRL SHIFT ALT +? I cant think of something.

Comment: Adobe After Effects to create a folder :)